# Can I list an occupied property for rent prior to lease renewal date?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, pennsylvania, lease

I own a property in Philadelphia, PA that I lease two tenants. Per the lease, they are required to inform me if they would like to renew the yearly lease on September 1st, one month before the end of the lease term on October 1. They have not yet informed me that they officially intend to renew. Can I list the property online to assess interest in a raised rent value prior to hearing from my tenants? Can I tell them “no” if they say they’d like to renew if/after ive found different tenants through this listing?

Comment: What does the lease say about informing them that you will not be extending the lease? Does the city require you to extend their lease automatically if they request it? How does the current health crisis factor into the renewal rules?

Comment: Are you required to *actually* rent out the property you listed?

Comment: A realtor would probably have enough information about current demand and comparable properties' rents to give you an estimate without actually listing the property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A real estate agent will not accept such a listing.
In many cases, the existing tenant has no obligation to allow a showing while they still occupy the rental. Once they give notice, you can list it, but still need their permission to enter the premises.

Listing it without having notice runs the risk of you being sued for false advertising. I would not be happy to consider an apartment or house that's not actually available to me.

If you do this absent any help, how will you respond to such a call inquiring? "Yes, that's the price. No, can't show it to you. Call me 9/1, but even then, it might no be available."

Comment: First sentence is confusing to me, I don't know any landlords who list their rentals via real estate agents nor tenants who find rentals via agents outside of high-end or corporate housing.

Comment: I live in MA, have a real estate license, and have listed many rentals. I visited NYC with my daughter last weekend to look for an apartment, and there was a real estate agent showing us his listings. Not sure why this is confusing, just clarifying, that an agent won't take such a listing.

Comment: You'd only list rentals that are already vacant? That seems bizarre and is certainly not standard practice. PA laws do not prevent landlords from showing an occupied unit.

Comment: I would wait to see if the tenant already there gave notice. i.e. I would not list an apartment that had a strong chance of not being available. The OP's motivation is to test the waters, the listing is not genuine. If the tenant gives notice, our lease allows showing during the 30 day period prior to the move. But not before then, and certainly not before notice is given. If you have state-specific expertise, by all means, offer a detailed answer.

Comment: Ah, I see your point, I thought you were hung up on the listing while occupied part but you're just saying if someone told you they hadn't decided/given notice about renewal then that ambiguity is the issue.

Comment: Right. OP may have experience that no one stays, and my objection is a non-issue. The owner I worked for had a 90%+ retention rate. And this approach strikes me as disingenuous. This is the point of the 30 day notice. Good talk.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I list the property online to assess interest in a raised rent
> value prior to hearing from my tenants?

Likely yes, but you may want to include a "Do not visit / do not disturb tenants" warning.

> Can I tell them “no” if they say they’d like to renew if/after ive
> found different tenants through this listing?

You can issue a non-renewal notice, but make sure it is timely. Don't wait for the tenants to act. If no one acts, the lease may automatically convert to a month-to-month lease. If that happens, it would grant the tenants rights under Philadelphia's [Good Cause eviction law](https://www.thedp.com/article/2019/10/philadelphia-tenant-rights-renters-protection-housing-penn):

> The law prevents an owner or landlord from issuing a lease termination
> or non-renewal notice without first showing a “good cause” reason.
> This rule applies to leases that are for less than one year, including
> those that convert to shorter time frames like month to month.

Answer (score -1):

A property owner can evict a tenant for several reasons, however, it is a must you should go through the proper legal channels. That means you can list an occupied property for rent prior to lease renewal notice. However, you have to provide the tenant due notice. The amount of days necessary for due notice varies by state and can range from nearly immediate to 30 days or more. As your tenants haven't informed you regarding the renewal **(as per the lease)**, you can proceed.

If it is a written agreement, you can say a "no" if they say they’d like to renew if you have found different tenants through the listing. However, if it is a verbal agreement, it can be revoked by the tenant as there isn't any proof. ( in this case you have the legal back up as it is written agreement)